# Firebase authentication using phone number on server side using spring

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, react-native

We are trying to authenticate a user using their phone number and we pass this data to the backend (server) but we do not know how to authenticate or create a new user in firebase on the server side. Backend is Springboot and Java with firebase plugin. I know this can be done from the client app but I am wondering how to do it using the server

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any way to implement it?

Comment: Have you implemented this? If yes, then please answer your own question, it will help many others.